# swipeRefreshLayout onRefresh crashing the app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement swipe refresh layout.

I can pull down the view, the circular arrow is showing, but when i leave it, the app crashes.

here is my code

```
public class MIBActivity extends Activity {


private SwipeRefreshLayout mibSwipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mib);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final MIBTask mibTask = new MIBTask(MIBActivity.this);
    mibTask.execute();

    mibSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.mib_swipe_refresh_layout);
    mibSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {

                    mibTask.execute();

                    mibSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            //mibSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

    mibSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}
```

I am calling an asyncTask to update my textviews.

Calling `mibSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` inside onPreExecute and calling `mibSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` inside onPostExecute from asyncTask.

Here is my layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mib_swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mv.mvqueuestatus.MIBActivity"
android:background="@color/green">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/MIBLayoutBelow"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMIB3"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMIB4"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/MIBLayoutBelow"
    android:id="@+id/MIBLayoutAbove"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMIB1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/txtMIB2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Note: When I add the scrollView, the layout id distorted and the textviews appear one above the other.

Here is my logcat

```
01-20 11:50:39.286    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-20 11:50:39.442    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-20 11:50:39.442    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7917c50, tid 2856
01-20 11:50:39.450    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-20 11:50:39.450    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-20 11:50:39.502    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 11:50:39.502    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-20 11:50:39.506    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 11:50:39.510    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-20 11:50:39.510    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 11:50:39.510    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-20 11:51:32.410    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 136K, 5% free 3845K/4044K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
01-20 11:51:32.418    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 3% free 4216K/4344K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 11:51:32.418    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.593MB for 2536932-byte allocation
01-20 11:51:32.422    2856-2867/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 6693K/6824K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 11:51:32.478    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 11:51:33.918    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
01-20 11:51:34.610    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 11:51:35.110    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
01-20 11:51:37.326    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 11:51:37.742    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
01-20 11:51:38.394    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 11:51:38.818    2856-2856/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
01-20 12:03:41.738    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 4% free 3924K/4056K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-20 12:03:41.738    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.889MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-20 12:03:41.742    2945-2954/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 4945K/5084K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:03:41.874    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-20 12:03:41.874    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7912710, tid 2945
01-20 12:03:41.902    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-20 12:03:41.902    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-20 12:03:41.962    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:03:41.962    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-20 12:03:41.966    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:03:41.966    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-20 12:03:41.970    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:03:41.970    2945-2945/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-20 12:08:39.826    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 4% free 3773K/3900K, paused 2ms, total 11ms
01-20 12:08:39.826    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.741MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-20 12:08:39.846    3003-3012/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4794K/4928K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
01-20 12:08:39.858    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4795K/4928K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:08:39.858    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.301MB for 588812-byte allocation
01-20 12:08:39.870    3003-3012/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5370K/5504K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
01-20 12:08:39.974    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-20 12:08:39.974    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7914fb8, tid 3003
01-20 12:08:39.986    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-20 12:08:39.986    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-20 12:08:40.086    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:08:40.090    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-20 12:08:40.094    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:08:40.102    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-20 12:08:40.106    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:08:40.106    3003-3003/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-20 12:25:27.626    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-20 12:25:27.746    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 4% free 3773K/3908K, paused 2ms, total 10ms
01-20 12:25:27.746    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.741MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-20 12:25:27.750    3125-3134/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4794K/4936K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:25:27.778    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4796K/4936K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-20 12:25:27.778    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.301MB for 588812-byte allocation
01-20 12:25:27.786    3125-3134/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5370K/5512K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
01-20 12:25:27.802    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5373K/5512K, paused 12ms, total 13ms
01-20 12:25:27.806    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.847MB for 570252-byte allocation
01-20 12:25:27.826    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5929K/6072K, paused 2ms, total 9ms
01-20 12:25:27.862    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-20 12:25:27.862    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb77fd368, tid 3125
01-20 12:25:27.882    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-20 12:25:27.882    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-20 12:25:27.982    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:25:27.990    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-20 12:25:27.990    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:25:28.018    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-20 12:25:28.022    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:25:28.022    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-20 12:25:29.930    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:26:11.630    3125-3125/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:29:58.490    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 4% free 3773K/3912K, paused 2ms, total 5ms
01-20 12:29:58.494    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.741MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-20 12:29:58.498    3192-3201/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4794K/4940K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:29:58.598    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4796K/4940K, paused 1ms, total 44ms
01-20 12:29:58.602    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.301MB for 588812-byte allocation
01-20 12:29:58.606    3192-3201/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5370K/5516K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
01-20 12:29:58.642    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5373K/5516K, paused 21ms, total 33ms
01-20 12:29:58.642    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.847MB for 570252-byte allocation
01-20 12:29:58.650    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5929K/6076K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:29:58.690    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-20 12:29:58.694    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7915ec0, tid 3192
01-20 12:29:58.706    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-20 12:29:58.706    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-20 12:29:58.750    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:29:58.750    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-20 12:29:58.754    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:29:58.758    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-20 12:29:58.758    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:29:58.758    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-20 12:30:00.890    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:30:09.366    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:30:16.106    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:30:23.546    3192-3192/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:34:18.486    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 35K, 3% free 3773K/3876K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
01-20 12:34:18.486    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.741MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-20 12:34:18.498    3263-3272/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4794K/4904K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
01-20 12:34:18.530    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4796K/4904K, paused 1ms, total 16ms
01-20 12:34:18.534    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.301MB for 588812-byte allocation
01-20 12:34:18.534    3263-3272/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 5370K/5480K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:34:18.594    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 5933K/6040K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-20 12:34:18.698    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
01-20 12:34:18.698    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb77db180, tid 3263
01-20 12:34:18.726    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
01-20 12:34:18.726    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
01-20 12:34:18.790    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:34:18.790    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
01-20 12:34:18.794    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:34:18.810    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
01-20 12:34:18.810    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
01-20 12:34:18.810    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-20 12:34:35.862    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:34:43.478    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:34:49.822    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:34:56.638    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:34:57.990    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:35:04.918    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:35:18.130    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-20 12:35:23.534    3263-3263/com.mv.mvqueuestatus W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Can you tell me what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

are you using Genymotion simulation, I found it can't display SwipeRefreshLayout correctly, maybe you can test on a real device.